# how to compile a proto file to a single php file

Tags: php, protocol-buffers

I tried to compile a protobuf file in php by using protoc, but when I wrote more then one message in the 'pbfile', the protoc gave me so many php files. The 'pbfile' contents are:

```proto
//test.proto begin
syntax="proto3";
message C2S_AcctLogin {}
message S2C_AcctLogin {}
//test.proto end
```

When I execute this cmd:

```
protoc.exe --php_out="." -I="." test.proto
```

...then I get two files: S2C_AcctLogin.php and C2S_AcctLogin.php

How can I get a single php file named 'test.php' like in cpp language?

Comment: it is largely up to the per-language plugin to decide how the files come out; it may well not be possible to do this automatically - in particular, I don't see any relevant options in `descriptor.proto` for this (just options for the php class prefix, namespace, and metadata namespace). You may need to either a: just live with it, or b: find a separate dedicated "merge multiple php files into a single file" tool.